# Adding css/js code resources into a Marketing Cloud Landing Page (Preference Center)

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, css, cloudpage, code

I want to start by saying I am very new to html, css, and js. So this may seem like a stupid questions.

After I upload my CSS file upload into Marketing Cloud using the code resource, I have added the following code into my cloud page:

This for css: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cloud.emails.urladdress.com/css_assets">`

This for js: `<script src="https://cloud.emails.urladdress.com/js_assets"></script>`

The page is not picking up the information from these files.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you publish the page or just viewing on preview?

Comment: Are you referencing correct URLs? To make sure you can use `%%=CloudPagesURL(123)=%%` instead of the actual URL of the code resources to reference the correct page even though the URL might have been changed.

Comment: I can assure you that the code you've included, as written, should work. Possible problems: 1 - is the page published? 2 - is the content in the pages that are being linked to also published? 3 - are you placing these reference links in a page, or in a content block that is in a page? Content blocks DO NOT support JS or referenced CSS (there's a way around that though), and will remove your lines from the rendered page.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  It is in a content block.  I will change that and see if it works.  Thanks again!